# Transparent code does not working on Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I searched and tried some answers about it but it doesn't work.

i tried like this:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
```

and

```
root.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff,0);
```

as i said it does not work i just saw black screen :/

here is my "init" function :

```js
function init() {
  var root = new THREERoot({
    createCameraControls:false,
  antialias: true,
    fov:60
  });
  root.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
  root.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
  root.camera.position.set(0, 0, 400);

  var textAnimation = createTextAnimation();
  textAnimation.position.y = -40;
  root.scene.add(textAnimation);

  var tl = new TimelineMax({
    repeat:-1,
    repeatDelay:0.25,
    yoyo:true
  });
  tl.fromTo(textAnimation, 4,
    {animationProgress:0.0},
    {animationProgress:1.0, ease:Power1.easeInOut},
    0
  );

  createTweenScrubber(tl);
}
```

this is what i am using :

https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/xVrMMO

Comment: There are literally hundreds of possible reasons for this. Can you post your code in a concise and minimal example so the behavior can be replicated? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I wrote there the main function of my code.I think the problem can be solved from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your Three.js project to be transparent, you need to set its renderer's alpha parameter to true:

```
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
```

This way, the parts that don't render anything will show the background of your HTML page, so if your HTML background is `#ff0000`, then you should see red.

However, you're essentially disabling the transparency when you perform

```
  root.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
```

This line paints a white background on every frame, which means it's no longer transparent.

Also, I can't see your `renderer.render(scene, camera);` line, because your code example is so narrow in scope.

Comment: First thanks for helping, so i tried to remove this part :

" root.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff); "

of my code but then the script broken i mean the screen was just black.

there is a code like this :
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias:params.antialias
  });

i wrote there 'alpha' code before but it does not working as well.
what should i do now ? :/

Comment: 1. What's your HTML background color? 2. What's your camera pointing at? 3. Does your scene have no lights and is just rendering a dark room? 4. What's inside `params.antialias`? 5. Are you calling `renderer.render()`? There are too many variables to pinpoint the problem. You're not giving me much to work with with your limited code. I recommend you head to https://jsfiddle.net/ , build your example, and then post it here so we can help you.

Comment: Hello again, im really sorry beacuse i am a beginner really i am.

https://jsfiddle.net/ms7u5cnw/1/

i tried to put the codes here but it does not work at all i dont know why :/

also you can see the what im trying to use :

https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/xVrMMO

Comment: Are you sure that the reason you're not seeing anything isn't because it's black letters on a black background? See here: https://codepen.io/marquizzo/pen/MzopEV I added 'background: #f90' to the CSS, removed `.setClearColor()` on line 9 and added `alpha: true` to the renderer on line 227. With those 3 lines, the canvas is now transparent, letting you see the orange from the CSS background.

Comment: Thank you so much, the reason was i wrote alpha:true code in a wrong way thats why. Now its working :)